# Delete large amount of records cause database lock

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several million records in Log table which would like to delete. I use SQL below to delete a table in 500 records chunk to prevent database lock, unfortunately, the Log table still gets locked and all new connections fail to access that table.

```
DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;
SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;


WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
  BEGIN

   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   -- Delete some small number of rows at a time
     DELETE TOP (500)  Log 
     WHERE UserId = 3905

     SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;

   COMMIT TRANSACTION   
END
```

The SQL is run from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and when I click the STOP button from the menu to stop SQL execution the lock still remains on Log table and still no new connections allowed.

When I try to close Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio itself I get the confirmation dialog

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these transactions before closing the window?

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

&Yes
&No
Cancel
------------------------------
```

And only when I click on NO button the table gets unlocked.

Then what is the correct way to delete a large number of records from a table without bringing the database down?

Comment: I think its best to also make a try catch, so you can rollback if any error occurs. Probably because of this you get this dialog from SSMS. You left a transaction open on your error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to the beginning of the script. This will ensure the transaction is rolled back if the query is cancelled by the client application, due to a timeout or manual cancel.

I would not expect your script to lock the entire table if the table has an index on `UserId`, facilitating more granular locks and improve concurrency. Also, make sure the literal (integer here) matches the column type. The table must be scanned for each `DELETE` iteration if there is no index or the index is not used because the column value must be converted to int for the comparison due to [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) (e.g. if the column data type is `varchar`, the literal should be enclosed in single quotes to permit an index seek rather than scan).

Comment: UserId has the IX_UserId(non-unique, non-clustered) index.

Comment: @Tomas, I added a note on the matching data type, another important consideration.

Comment: The SET XACT_ABORT ON; solves the problem and deletion goes as planned without locking the table.